# On select change multiply two select value with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a table with a form.

I want, on each form change, to multiply the quantity by the unit price and place the result in an input.

My JS code is actually this one:

```
$('select.BIL_item_quantity, select.BIL_item_id').on('change', function() {
    var quantity = $(this).closest('select.BIL_item_quantity').find(':selected').val();
    var rate = $(this).closest('select.BIL_item_id').find(':selected').data('item-rate');
    $(this).closest('tr').find('input.BIL_item_total_rate').val(quantity*rate);
});
```

But it doesn't work.

Any help with this please ?

Thanks.

https://jsfiddle.net/uvdv812z/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few modifications and optimizations:

```
  $('select.BIL_item_quantity, select.BIL_item_id').on('change', function() {
    var parent = $(this).parents("tr:first");
    var quantity = parent.find('select.BIL_item_quantity').val();
    var rate = parent.find('select.BIL_item_id').find(':selected').data('item-rate');
    parent.find('input.BIL_item_total_rate').val((parseInt(quantity) * parseInt(rate)).toFixed(2));
  });
```

Demo: 
https://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/uvdv812z/3/

Comment: Ho wow! it's working. Thanks. Last thing: how I can keep the `.00` at the end if the total do not have any number after comma ?

Comment: @user8201518 Use parseFloat instead of parseInt

Comment: It makes the same. :(

Comment: @user8201518 Try now

Comment: It does not work if the price of the item is 6.50. It rounds the number to display `.00`. Do you have a solution for this case please ?